# How to create directory in c++ and make it share and writable for everyone?

Tags: winapi, permissions, shared, create-directory

I need to create a directory in my vc++ application (which will store the ftpd backup files) and i need to *give EVERYONE full access permissions* so that a *process from other remote system can refer to that directory and can delete the files in that directory*.

`CreateDirectory(sFilePath, NULL)`

How to fill the second argument in this above mentioned API.?

Or Is there any other way of achieving the requirement?

Comment: this is a question about winapi, not c++ (fixed tags). why not read the winapi docu about that. you allready found the correct function.

Answer (score 4):

This is from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

#include <windows.h>
#include <sddl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "advapi32.lib")

BOOL CreateMyDACL(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *);

void main()
{
     SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES  sa;

     sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
     sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;  

     // Call function to set the DACL. The DACL
     // is set in the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES 
     // lpSecurityDescriptor member.
     if (!CreateMyDACL(&sa))
     {
         // Error encountered; generate message and exit.
         printf("Failed CreateMyDACL\n");
         exit(1);
     }

     // Use the updated SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES to specify
     // security attributes for securable objects.
     // This example uses security attributes during
     // creation of a new directory.
     if (0 == CreateDirectory(TEXT("C:\\MyFolder"), &sa))
     {
         // Error encountered; generate message and exit.
         printf("Failed CreateDirectory\n");
         exit(1);
     }

     // Free the memory allocated for the SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR.
     if (NULL != LocalFree(sa.lpSecurityDescriptor))
     {
         // Error encountered; generate message and exit.
         printf("Failed LocalFree\n");
         exit(1);
     }
}


// CreateMyDACL.
//    Create a security descriptor that contains the DACL 
//    you want.
//    This function uses SDDL to make Deny and Allow ACEs.
//
// Parameter:
//    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES * pSA
//    Pointer to a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure. It is your
//    responsibility to properly initialize the 
//    structure and to free the structure's 
//    lpSecurityDescriptor member when you have
//    finished using it. To free the structure's 
//    lpSecurityDescriptor member, call the 
//    LocalFree function.
// 
// Return value:
//    FALSE if the address to the structure is NULL. 
//    Otherwise, this function returns the value from the
//    ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor 
//    function.
BOOL CreateMyDACL(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES * pSA)
{
     // Define the SDDL for the DACL. This example sets 
     // the following access:
     //     Built-in guests are denied all access.
     //     Anonymous logon is denied all access.
     //     Authenticated users are allowed 
     //     read/write/execute access.
     //     Administrators are allowed full control.
     // Modify these values as needed to generate the proper
     // DACL for your application. 
     TCHAR * szSD = TEXT("D:")       // Discretionary ACL
        TEXT("(D;OICI;GA;;;BG)")     // Deny access to 
                                     // built-in guests
        TEXT("(D;OICI;GA;;;AN)")     // Deny access to 
                                     // anonymous logon
        TEXT("(A;OICI;GRGWGX;;;AU)") // Allow 
                                     // read/write/execute 
                                     // to authenticated 
                                     // users
        TEXT("(A;OICI;GA;;;BA)");    // Allow full control 
                                     // to administrators

    if (NULL == pSA)
        return FALSE;

     return ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
                szSD,
                SDDL_REVISION_1,
                &(pSA->lpSecurityDescriptor),
                NULL);
}
```

Comment: NetShareAdd API helped me in sharing the directory created with access all permissions.